# Changing parent page meta tags from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How can I change the Meta Tags (description, title) of a parent page when it loads using an iframe that is located in the same page ?

Comment: basically the same way you would be doing if the script was in the page self, except you'll be prefixing some instructions with `parent.`

Comment: Changing them with client-side scripting would have no impact on search engines, which are the main reason for using them (especially `meta` elements; the `title` has other impact, too). So are you sure you are solving the right problem?

Comment: Thank you Jukka. I am aware for the uses of mata tags so, yes, I'm sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`parent.document.title = 'something';`

for change parent title and

`parent.document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute('content','something');`

for change parent description.